# Bot will react to my answer "Correct" or "Wrong Answer" . But when I answer the correct answer, it keeps saying wrong answer

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm quite a noob when it comes to discord.py and I'm struggling to define `m` in the `wait_for` command. I tried to define `m` but when I answer the question the bot will not react at all. This is my full code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
class Trivia(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def trivia(self, ctx):
        def check(m):  # Checks that the author of the command gives the answer
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        await ctx.send('**Welcome to this Trivia! There will be 5 questions that you have to answer.**')

        question = ['Who invented The Theory of Special Relavity?',
                    'Who created Algebra?',
                    "What is Newton's third law? **use 'and' instead of '&'**",
                    'Who discover prism?']
        responses = ['Albert Einstein',
                    'al-Khwarizmi',
                    'Action and Reaction',
                    'Isaac Newton']

        for i in question:
            await ctx.send(i) # Send the question

            try:
                await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)  # Wait for the message
                if message in responses:
                    await ctx.send('Correct Answer!')
            except:
                await ctx.send('Wrong Answer!')
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Trivia(client))
```

Comment: i dont know what's your error but using `try` `except` swallows *any* errors. try `import traceback` and `except Exception: traceback.print_exc()` to get the actual error. that can help

Comment: okay will try! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the returned message to a variable:

```py
message = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=check)
message = message.content
```